# ERROR in Maximum call stack size exceeded Angular 10 update

Tags: angular

I have been searching non stop for a solution but after successful update from Angular 8 to 9 I am encountering a ERROR in Maximum call stack size exceeded executing npm run build. This happened after updating all imports per ngx-bootstrap documentation and it solved hundreds of errors not finding component/module error only to get this error. Here is my package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "ecdt",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-interfaces": "ng build interfaces-app",
    "watch-interfaces": "ng build interfaces-app --watch",
    "copyinterfacescripts": "copyfiles --flat ./../../wwwroots/E-ClosingSecured/ECDT/interfaces/angular_bundle_interfaces_imports.forminc ./../../../ec-production/itec/html",
    "copyscripts": "copyfiles --flat ./../../wwwroots/E-ClosingSecured/ECDT/ui/angular_bundle_imports.forminc ./../../../ec-production/itec/html",
    "watch": "ng build --watch",
    "prod": "ng build --prod --aot",
    "prod-interfaces": "ng build interfaces-app --prod --aot",
    "postbuild": "npm run copyscripts",
    "postbuild-interfaces": "npm run copyinterfacescripts",
    "postprod": "npm run copyscripts",
    "postprod-interfaces": "npm run copyinterfacescripts",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "full-build": "npm run prod && npm run prod-interfaces"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/localize": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "^10.2.5",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.12.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^8.0.4",
    "@schematics/angular": "^10.2.4",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.9.0",
    "angular-input-masks": "^4.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.9.1",
    "component": "^0.19.9",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "is-promise": "^4.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.3.4",
    "ng2-completer": "3.0.3",
    "ng2-dragula": "^2.1.1",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.4.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^6.3.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-currency": "^2.5.3",
    "ngx-doc-viewer": "^1.4.0",
    "ngx-drag-drop": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-mask": "^8.1.7",
    "ngx-moment": "^3.5.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^5.1.1",
    "ngx-typeahead": "^6.2.1",
    "ngx-xml2json": "^1.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "save": "^2.9.0",
    "simplebar-angular": "2.1.0",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "timers": "^0.1.1",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "updated": "^1.3.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.23",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1002.4",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "^0.1002.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^10.2.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.1",
    "codelyzer": "^0.0.28",
    "copyfiles": "^2.4.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "ng-packagr": "^10.1.2",
    "ng2-smart-table": "1.7.2",
    "ngx-datatable": "^1.0.3",
    "npm": "^6.14.17",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~10.9.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.10"
  }
}
```

ng --version

```
Angular CLI: 10.2.4
Node: 12.19.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 10.2.5
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, localize, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: No

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.1002.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.1002.4
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   0.1002.4
@angular-devkit/core               10.2.4
@angular-devkit/schematics         10.2.4
@angular/cdk                       10.2.7
@angular/cli                       10.2.4
@schematics/angular                10.2.4
@schematics/update                 0.1002.4
ng-packagr                         10.1.2
rxjs                               6.6.7
typescript                         3.9.10
```

tsconfig

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": ["./node_modules/@angular/*"],
      "framework": [
        "dist/framework/framework",
        "dist/framework"
      ]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "enableIvy": false,
  }
}
```

Error log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\joe.stephens\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.17
3 info using node@v12.19.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle ecdt@0.0.0~prebuild: ecdt@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle ecdt@0.0.0~build: ecdt@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle ecdt@0.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle ecdt@0.0.0~build: PATH: C:\Users\joe.stephens\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\ec-webfiles\Source\ECDT\node_modules\.bin;C:\ProgramData\Boxstarter;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python310\Scripts\;C:\Python310\;C:\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Python39\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Sheerpower\;C:\Sheerpower\sphandlers\;C:\Sheerpower\sptools\;C:\Sheerpower\ars\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\joe.stephens\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\joe.stephens\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\joe.stephens\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle ecdt@0.0.0~build: CWD: C:\ec-webfiles\Source\ECDT
10 silly lifecycle ecdt@0.0.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'ng build' ]
11 silly lifecycle ecdt@0.0.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle ecdt@0.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: ecdt@0.0.0 build: `ng build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\joe.stephens\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\joe.stephens\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid ecdt@0.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\ec-webfiles\Source\ECDT
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19044
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\joe.stephens\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v12.19.1
19 verbose npm  v6.14.17
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error ecdt@0.0.0 build: `ng build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the ecdt@0.0.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Is there a stack trace with the "max call stack size exceeded" error you could provide?

Comment: @Tanner I added the log for the error above

Comment: ng serve --aot results in ECDT does not exist:
[error] Error: Project "ECDT" does not exist.
    at WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost.findProjectTarget (C:\ec-webfiles\Source\ECDT\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js:123:19)
    at WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost.getOptionsForTarget (C:\ec-webfiles\Source\ECDT\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js:74:33)
    at core_1.experimental.jobs.createJobHandler.name (C:\ec-webfiles\Source\ECDT\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\src\architect.js:172:21)

Comment: This started after I updated all of the imports for ngx-bootstrap to be specific /modal or /tooltip or /datepicker etc....